# Is there a way how to tell in css that I'm on custom post type page in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have **custom post** type called *places* and I want to do some css edits for it's edit page. is there a way how to tell in css that I'm on that page?

Something like `.places #titlewrap`. So far I wasn't able to find any css selector that I could use for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, just check the class in the body, and then you can do this `body.thecustompostclass .yourclass{...}

Comment: LoL how could I overlook something like this :D thank you so much.